# Deploy Keycloak on Native Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, keycloak

I want to deploy Kubernetes on Native Kubernetes cluster v1.29.2. I tried this:

Deployment:

```
kubectl create -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/keycloak/keycloak-quickstarts/latest/kubernetes/keycloak.yaml
```

Cluster:

```
8.8.8.101 (control plane IP)
8.8.8.102 (work node IP)
```

I configured DNS record to point to a control plane:

```
Record name: auth.my_domain.org
Record type: A
Value: 8.8.8.101 (control plane IP)
```

How should I configure Keyclock to be accessible on both nodes when i type the domain into web browser?